# Min length for text area in my form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to set a min length and a max length for my text area box on my website. I know for max i can do it in html, but min you cannot. Could someone help me with this? I can do if, else statements but that would be after the form is submitted. I want it to tell the user the length is too short before he/she even submits it. I think jquery would be the best but really unsure.

Code listed below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 15 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,150}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Need to enter at least 3 characters to submit this form.');
        e.preventDefault();

    }

});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> <u>Daily Dorm News</u> <br> The best place to get your latest Dorm news </h1>
<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Username:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>

Post:<br>
<div name="message">
<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message' required></textarea>
</div>
Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" required> <br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set min-length

```
pattern=".{5,}"  --> 5 characters minimum
```

set both min-length and max-length

```
pattern=".{5,100}"  --> 5 characters minimum and 100 maximum .
```

Example

```
<input type="text" name="test" pattern=".{20,100}" required >
```

to support Html5 in every browser use [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

---

Updated after OP's comment

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    if($('#message').val().length < 3){
       e.preventdefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: like so? "<div class='message'>
Post: <br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message' pattern=".{20,100}" required></textarea>
</div> "

Comment: hmm i tried, still let me submit eventhough I had only 1 character in the message field

Comment: use an hml5 validation polyfill to make sure it works in all browsers.

Comment: it does not validate, and does not work. I had it as "<div class='message'> Post: <br> <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message' pattern=".{20,100}" required></textarea> </div> "  but it still let me submit only 1 character. any idea how? I just want it so if you enter less then 3 characters it wont let you post

Comment: so that goes in the header of my html doc correct? Such as "<script>
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
    if($('#message').val().length < 3){
       e.preventdefault();
    }
});
</script>"

Answer (score 0):

Note that your HTML misses `</head>`. That said, the "pattern" attribute seems to work :

```
<input type="text" required="required" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}$" />
```

Here is another way of doing this  using Javascript. Just put this code into the `<head>` section, right after `$("#datepicker").datepicker();` :

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var nameValue = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}$/.test(nameValue)) {
        alert('failure');
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents from submitting
    }
});
```

Here is a demo combining both solutions : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/KbxM8/.

See also : http://api.jquery.com/submit/

---

I've tried something according to your comments :

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 15 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}$/.test(value.replace(/\n/g, ''))) {
        alert('Wrong value for "message".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked great thank you! Now can I use some form of this to MAKE the user submit atleast 1 numeral in the username field?

Comment: hold on, I had it working, but now its not. I put [name="name"] as [name="message"] since the name of the text area is message.

Comment: hmm? I dont get what you mean

Comment: I updated the code in the OP to show what I have, must just be a small error,

Comment: Nope, still does not have an effect. I tried putting it in the header, and in the form, neither worked. I'll paste the updated code above, just so you can see what I am doing. Hmm, so weird

Comment: think i might just use the pattern attribute, but id love to get java working if possible, seems like it should, the code looks perfect

Comment: now though, when i use "<input required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,350}" title="Please enter between 3 and 350 letters or numbers" name="message" type="text" id="post" >" since its not a text area, the cursor starts in the middle of the box, instead of at the top. And I cant use textarea since html5 textarea doesnt support pattern attribute

Comment: yes I tried that, let me try again though hehe, also, since the text area name="message" do i need to change it to message in the script?

Comment: updated code in op, doesnt work, but i think cause its not pointed towards the correct text area maybe?

Comment: ah, ok sorry, im all messed up now lol, changed the code to many times

Comment: its working, however even though I enter three characters, I still cannot submit the form :( I get the wrong value error, hmm

Comment: I mean like its working, the error message pops up when I dont submit enough characters, but even when I do submit 3 or more characters, it still gives me the error message and cant submit the form. OP updated with latest code.

Comment: I'm sorry @Terry, but I don't even understand what you want. Try to determine precisely the origin of your problem, clean up your code, then post a new question. Hold on ;)